# Your search might be slow because the index is not running

Tags: windows-server-2012

I have been put in charge of a Windows Server 2012 AWS instance and have no experience dealing with this operating system.

I get a warning when attempting to search using the file explorer which states "Your search might be slow because the index is not running."

I would like to enable search indexing but every tutorial I find using Google is for older versions of Windows Server and have not produced a solution.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to turn the indexing service on? This is fine if you have data that you actually want to index... otherwise it's just a waste of resources to turn it on just to get rid of a UI warning.

Answer (score 9):

On Windows Server 2012 according to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/

> 1. Start Server Manager.
> 2. Click Manage, and then click Add Roles and Features
> 3. On the Before You Begin page, click
> 4. On the Installation Type page, select Role-based or Feature-based Installation, and then click
> 5. On the Server Selection page, select the server or virtual hard disk on which to install Windows Search
> 6. On the Features page, select Windows Search Service, and then click
> 7. On the Confirmation page, verify that Windows Search Service is listed, and then click Install.

Comment: What if Windows Search Service is not listed on the Features page (#6)?

Comment: Click on the Features menu on the left side, then you will see Windows Search Service

Comment: There are clearly words missing at the end of your sentences for points 2, 3, 4, and 6.

Comment: Thanks, That was a good 7 steps of instructions. Just assumed but it will be nice to add an extra step between steps 5 and 6. On the Server Role page click next leaving selections unchanged. ie Do not check any Server Roles and move to Step 6. Thanks again very helpful!!

Comment: Thank you for the pointer on this one, saved me a bunch of time in trying to determine why one server was returning index search results, and the other was chugging. Users are happy now.

Comment: What about Windows Server 2008?